# Write a Stata eclass program that only returns a vector of p-values

Tags: stata

**Edit: After one day I cross-posted this [Statalist](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1366665-write-an-eclass-program-that-only-returns-a-vector-of-p-values).**

I want to write my own `eclass` program to work with `eststo` and `esttab` from SSC's `esttab`.

I want to write a wrapper for `ranksum` so that I can get the p-values and add them to a table alongside the p-values from t-tests. From the `ereturn` help file it seems like I need to return a `b` matrix to comply with `eclass`, but I can't figure out how.

I commented the bad calls below. Making the table with means and t-tests is no problem (i.e., first 3 columns). But my `Wilcoxon3` command gives an error. I have tried with and without returning `b`, but I can't figure out the error, which is `invalid syntax`.

I am OK with any solution that puts the `ranksum` p-values into an `e()` container.

```
capture program drop Wilcoxon3
program define Wilcoxon3, eclass 
    version 13

    syntax varlist [if] [in], by(varname)
    marksample touse

    local names
    foreach v of varlist `varlist' {
        ranksum `v' if `touse', by(`by')
        matrix b = nullmat(b), 1
        matrix p = nullmat(p), 2*normprob(-abs(r(z)))
        local names `names' "`v'"

    }
    matrix colnames p = `names'

    // store results 
    ereturn post b
    ereturn matrix p

end

sysuse auto, clear
eststo clear

/* store means and t-tests */
estpost summarize price weight if !foreign
eststo

estpost summarize price weight if foreign
eststo

estpost ttest price weight, by(foreign)
eststo

/* /1* try to store rank-sum test *1/ */
/* Wilcoxon3 price weight, by(foreign) */
/* eststo */


/* table of means and t-tests */
esttab, cells("mean(pattern(1 0 0) fmt(3) label(!Foreign)) mean(pattern(0 1 0) fmt(3) label(Foreign)) p(star pattern(0 0 1) fmt(3) label(p))")

/* /1* try table of means, t-tests, and rank-sum tests *1/ */
/* esttab, cells("mean(pattern(1 0 0 0) fmt(3) label(!Foreign)) mean(pattern(0 1 0 0) fmt(3) label(Foreign)) p(star pattern(0 0 1 0) fmt(3) label(p)) p(star pattern(0 0 0 1) fmt(3) label(p))") */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received an answer on Statalist [here](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1366665-write-an-eclass-program-that-only-returns-a-vector-of-p-values).

This was a case of RTFM. The `ereturn post` syntax doesn't require rename and equal sign, but `ereturn matrix` does. This is clear if you focus on the syntax example provided at the top of the `ereturn` help page. The `=` is optional, but a new name is not.

The correct code is `ereturn matrix p = p`.